# How to install Java IntelliJ IDE on External SSD for Mac?

Tags: external-disk, java, apple-silicon

My internal Apple Silicon Mac is only 256 GB and IntelliJ IDE for Java takes up 2 GB, when I tried moving the IntelliJ from the Applications to my External SSD, I couldn't open the IDE. The prompt said, the file is damaged or moved. Is there a way to install it on External SSD?

Comment: What format is the SSD? (If it's not HFS+ or APFS, then it probably doesn't support all the Mac metadata needed for an application.)

Comment: It's exFAT, let me try changing it. Thanks